# Empty request is sending thru Curl that gives 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache, curl

I have set parameters thru curl using curl_setopt_array function but when I print the options that I set e.g. headers then it shows that [header_size] => 0 and [request_size] => 0 
PFB the code snippet.

```
$url='https://mysite.com:443/login';
$headers=array('contentType:application/json','X-API-Key:34SDFSDFvvsdfsdEERER45');
$keyPass="passphrase";

    $ret=curl_setopt_array($handle, array(
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_CAINFO => 'C:\wamp\www\server.pem',
    //CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'uid=>username,password=>pwd',
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0",
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array("uid"=>'username',"password"=>'pwd'),
    CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => TRUE,
    ));
}

if (false==$ret) {
  echo "Unable to set curl options";
}
    $info=curl_getinfo($handle);
    print_R($info); 

    $response=curl_exec($handle);

    $info=curl_getinfo($handle);
    print_R($info); 

Output after execution

<html>
    <title>Consume Rest With Curl</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    Array //request to server
    (
        [url] => https://mysite.com:443/login
        [content_type] => 
        [http_code] => 0
        [header_size] => 0
        [request_size] => 0
        [filetime] => 0
        [ssl_verify_result] => 0
        [redirect_count] => 0
        [total_time] => 0
        [namelookup_time] => 0
        [connect_time] => 0
        [pretransfer_time] => 0
        [size_upload] => 0
        [size_download] => 0
        [speed_download] => 0
        [speed_upload] => 0
        [download_content_length] => -1
        [upload_content_length] => -1
        [starttransfer_time] => 0
        [redirect_time] => 0
        [certinfo] => Array
            (
            )

        [primary_ip] => 
        [primary_port] => 0
        [local_ip] => 
        [local_port] => 0
        [redirect_url] => 
    )
    Array //response from server
    (
        [url] => https://mysite.com:443/login
        [content_type] => 
        [http_code] => 500
        [header_size] => 25
        [request_size] => 362
        [filetime] => -1
        [ssl_verify_result] => 0
        [redirect_count] => 0
        [total_time] => 0.265
        [namelookup_time] => 0
        [connect_time] => 0.031
        [pretransfer_time] => 0.14
        [size_upload] => 248
        [size_download] => 0
        [speed_download] => 0
        [speed_upload] => 935
        [download_content_length] => -1
        [upload_content_length] => 248
        [starttransfer_time] => 0.187
        [redirect_time] => 0
        [certinfo] => Array
            (
            )

        [primary_ip] => server ip
        [primary_port] => 443
        [local_ip] => client ip
        [local_port] => 50909
        [redirect_url] => 
    )
    Error --> The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error
    </body>
    </html>
```

I would like to know when we make request then all the parameters in array shd show some values (e.g. header size, request size). Please correct me if I am wrong or Is there any wrong with the code.
I verified this with server side and it seems that the header is reaching to server but other request parameters are empty. I am just passing username and password i.e. body in Post Fields.

Regds

Answer (score 1):

Actually change these parameters like this..

```
 CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE,
```

Comment: while switching verification off helps, you can also just disable https at all and use http. The non-security is the same. It looks like the author explicitly tried to set a CAINFO so that the server certificate gets verified. So the question is not how to disable verification but how to do correct verification

Comment: not working, i used this code , i am getting 500 error but not showing

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE,
```

Because you handling HTTPS server so this contents are very securable. so you must turn of the ssl

**Updated**

you need to add http header `Accept: application/json';`

```
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string1); //Send the data to the file
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $path1 );
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json')); 
curl_setopt( $ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header );
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
```

Comment: I tried this but the same error. Only thing I know is the server require the request in JSON format.

Comment: I did the way you have mentioned but I am receiving [http_code] => 500
in server response. But when I added "Content-Type:  multipart/mixed; boundary=1995021309105517" in headers then I get following error in server header.

Comment: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultco 
body---: de>
            <faultstring>Error in assertion processing</faultstring>
            <faultactor>ssg</faultactor>
            <detail>
                <l7:policyResult
                    status="Multipart stream ended before a terminating boundary was encountered" xmlns:l7="http://www.layer7tech.com/ws/policy/fault"/>
            </detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: give me your post url and give me your username and password. then only i will give a better solution to you

Comment: it is being called in post method.

Answer (score 0):

After analyse the request found that we are sending wrong headers (contentType instead of Content-Type) and in post fields of curl we are sending username and password in non json format. so we sent that in json format and encode it using json_encode before sending.

Thanks for all who has help to answer this.

Regds

Answer (score 0):

try this method to get your solution.

```
function callThirdPartyPostAPI( $url,$postField ,$method = 'get'  )
    {
        $ch1 = curl_init();

    if(  strtolower($method)  == 'get')
     {
         curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
         curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
         curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
     }
     elseif(   strtolower($method)  == 'post' )
     {
         curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
         curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
         curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
         curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
         curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
         curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postField,true));
     }

        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch1),true);
        $err = curl_error($ch1);
        curl_close($ch1);

        if ($err) {
            return ["status"=>"cURL Error #:" . $err];
        } else {
            return $response;
        }
    }
```

i am calling like this way in get Get method.

> https://www.XXXX.in/XXX/xxx/onxxxxn/revert-back-admission?id=3&h=23jj3gghj131