# Error using curl php, getting http status 500

Tags: php, web-services, curl

Hello stackoverflow community, I am having some problems when I try to send a request with curl in php, but something odd is that I have 2 servers, and when I use my code in one of them I get the response Im looking for, but in the other one I get the following response:

[Http status code 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxfZo.png)

As you can see it says "HTTP Status 500 - empty String", but why is that? in the other server I am not getting that with the same code

Thanks in advice to anyone who can help me out!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Empty request is sending thru Curl that gives 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950234/empty-request-is-sending-thru-curl-that-gives-500-internal-server-error)

Comment: Did you even read the stack trace? `NumberFormatException: empty string` The code expected an input of a number, you gave it nothing, and also failed to handle that error. Where is the code? We cant help you with code we can not see. Also, don';t post screen shots; is it really that hard to copy and paste some text? Also, you mentioned `php`, but this is clearly a Java Tomcat error page... This question is all over the place..

Answer (score 0):

Ok mistake by no posting my code, here it is

```
$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 443); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string_data); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$result = curl_exec($curl);
```